# Is it possible to use variables with `save-buffer` in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am trying to save a buffer to a file. In the name of the file I want to use the pane id. I use the following tmux command.

`save-buffer "$TMPDIR/tmux.#{pane_id}"`

This saves a file in `/tmp/tmux.#{pane_id}`. Other commands, like `run "echo $TMPDIR/tmux.#{pane_id}"`, gives the desired output, i.e. `/tmp/tmux.%1`.

I am using tmux 2.6.

Comment: @thrig This will not work if the pane is busy, but it suits me wll. If you want to leave the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround (with caveats) is to run a command to act on the output of `save-buffer` and in that command use tmux variables:

```
bind-key s run "tmux save-buffer - > ~/tmp/tmux-#{pane_id}"
```

Comment: What are the caveats?